# Convert json string to interpolation in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a json response as :

{
someText: "Order in {000} 12pm PST for early shipping";
cutofftime : "10000000"
}

What is the best approach to replace the '{000}' by the "cutofftime". Here the cutofftime is dynamic and the "someText" is static. I am using Angular 12.

I tried :
this.orderCutOffMessage = `Order in ${{ cutofftime }} 12pm PST for early shipping`;
which does not work and also the first and last part of the this.orderCutOffMessage should also come from the json response,

Answer (score 2):

`this.orderCutOffMessage = (yourJSONresponseVar).someText.replace('{000}',(yourJSONresponseVar).cutofftime);`